# how to Send records within the loop individually with Ajax

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-core, asp.net-ajax

I want to send and save the records inside the loop one by one with Ajax.Each record has a button to send information.
But when I want to send the record to the action method, only the information of the first record is sent.
I also want to make a Condition that if the user selects an item from dropdown,can send the record, otherwise a message will be displayed.

[image]

```
@model ModiranVira.ViewModels.GhrardadViewModel
@using ModiranVira.PublicClass
@{
    Layout = null;
    string numSpace = "#,##0.###";
}

<div class="container-fluid mt-5">

    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped text-sm">



        <thead class="text-center">

            <tr style="background-color:#416992; color: white">
                <th>نوع قرارداد</th>
                <th>مبلغ</th>
                <th>تاریخ شروع</th>
                <th>تاریخ پایان</th>
                <th>تعین کارشناس</th>
                <th>عملیات</th>

            </tr>

        </thead>


        @foreach (var item in Model.ghrardads)
        {
            <tr>

                @switch (@item.NoeaKhadmat)
                {
                    case 1:
                        <td>حسابرسی</td>


                        break;

                    case 2:
                        <td>مالیاتی</td>

                        break;

                    case 3:

                        <td>منابع انسانی</td>
                        break;

                }

                <td>@item.MablghGhrardad</td>

                <td>
                    @item.ShoroeeProjectDate
                </td>

                <td>
                    @item.PayanProjectDate
                </td>

                <input class="d-none" value="@item.id" id="GhradadID" />

                <td>

                    <select class="form-control" id="TaeenKarShnas" required autocomplete="off">
                        <option value="" default="" selected="">انتخاب کنید</option>
                        @foreach (var item1 in Model.Users)
                        {
                            <option value="@item1.Id">@item1.FirstName @item1.Family</option>

                        }
                    </select>

                </td>

                <td class="text-center">

                    <button id="btnstap39" type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-success"> <i class="fa fa-save"> </i>ذخیره </button>

                </td>

            </tr>

        }

    </table>

 <div id="ohsnap" class="col-md-4 col-xs-12 alert d-none" style="text-align:center;"></div>

</div>


<script>
        $("#btnstap39").on('click', function () {

        $.ajax({
            type: "Post",
            url: '@Url.Action("SubmitGhrardadStap39", "Project")',
            data: {

                'GhradadID': $("#GhradadID").val(),
                'TaeenKarShnas': $("#TaeenKarShnas").val(),

            }
        }).done(function (res) {
            if (res.status == 'ok') {

            $("#ohsnap").removeClass('hidden').removeClass('alert-danger').addClass('alert-success').html('گام دوم با موفقیت ثبت شد');
        setTimeout(function () {
            $('#ohsnap').fadeOut('fast');
        }, 2000)
        }
        });

        });

</script>
```

---

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult SubmitGhrardadStap39(int GhradadID, String TaeenKarShnas)
{
    var ghrar = _context.Ghrardad.Find(GhradadID);

    ghrar.UserID = TaeenKarShnas;

    _context.SaveChanges();

    return Json(new { status = "ok" });

}
```

Answer (score 2):

According to your description, the reason why you couldn't send the second data is you use jquery ID selector to select the ID. But all of your table GhradadID and TaeenKarShnas is the same ID, so you will always get the same(first) row.  To solve this issue, I suggest you could put the Item ID at the input and select ID and then click the button will find each different ID.

> I also want to make a Condition that if the user selects an item from dropdown,can send the record, otherwise a message will be displayed.

I suggest you could try to make a condition before the ajax and if the value is null then alter something.

More details, you could refer to below codes:

```
<div class="container-fluid mt-5">

    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped text-sm">



        <thead class="text-center">

            <tr style="background-color:#416992; color: white">
                <th>نوع قرارداد</th>
                <th>مبلغ</th>
                <th>تاریخ شروع</th>
                <th>تاریخ پایان</th>
                <th>تعین کارشناس</th>
                <th>عملیات</th>

            </tr>

        </thead>


        @foreach (var item in Model.ghrardads)
        {
            <tr>

                @switch (@item.NoeaKhadmat)
                {
                    case 1:
                        <td>حسابرسی</td>


                        break;

                    case 2:
                        <td>مالیاتی</td>

                        break;

                    case 3:

                        <td>منابع انسانی</td>
                        break;

                }

                <td>@item.MablghGhrardad</td>

                <td>
                    @item.ShoroeeProjectDate
                </td>

                <td>
                    @item.PayanProjectDate
                </td>

                <input class="d-none" value="@item.id" id="@string.Format("GhradadID{0}",item.id)" />

                <td>

                    <select class="form-control" id="@string.Format("TaeenKarShnas{0}",item.id)" required autocomplete="off">
                        <option value="" default="" selected="">انتخاب کنید</option>
                        @foreach (var item1 in Model.Users)
                        {
                            <option value="@item1.Id">@item1.FirstName @item1.Family</option>

                        }
                    </select>

                </td>

                <td class="text-center">

                    <button id="@item.id" type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-success ClicktPost"> <i class="fa fa-save"> </i>ذخیره </button>

                </td>

            </tr>

        }

    </table>



</div>

@section Scripts{ 

    <script>
        $(".ClicktPost").on('click', function (event) {
            var id = event.target.id;
          
            //Get the value according to Button's ID
            var GhradadID = $("#GhradadID" + id).val();
            var TaeenKarShnas = $("#TaeenKarShnas" + id).val();

            //If the TaeenKarShnas is null alert something
            if (TaeenKarShnas == '') {
                alert("please select dropdownlistvalue");
            } else {
                $.ajax({
            type: "Post",
            url: '@Url.Action("SubmitGhrardadStap39", "Home")',
            data: {

                'GhradadID': GhradadID,
                'TaeenKarShnas': TaeenKarShnas,

            }
        }).done(function (res) {
            if (res.status == 'ok') {

                $("#ohsnap").removeClass('hidden').removeClass('alert-danger').addClass('alert-success').html('گام دوم با موفقیت ثبت شد');
            }
        });

        }
        });


    </script>

}
```

Result:

If you don't select the value, you could refer to below image

[image]

If you don't select value, you could refer to below image

[image]

Comment: But I have an alert that I hid, and when the condition res.status == 'ok' was correct, this alert shows up and disappears after 2 seconds, but still works only for the first row. And this alert is not displayed when the second record line information is sent.

Comment: I edited the question. Please see the codes and help. Thank you

Comment: please guide me